# cant compile ast parser code in java

Tags: eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some ast parser  code in eclipse but I am unable to  import the 
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;

packages.

could some body tell me which jar file to download and where to add same that jar file in eclipse folder.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have those files downloaded already in eclipse\plugins folder i.e. in windows `C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.9.1.v20130905-0837.jar`

Of course you can download from internet as well
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.jdt.core/

Note that in order to run it as a stand alone application you will have to import such librariers (where xx stands for version and again they can be found in eclipse\plugins folder):

```
org.eclipse.core.contenttype_xx.jar
org.eclipse.core.jobs_xx.jar
org.eclipse.core.resources_xx.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_xx.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_xx.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_xx.jar
org.eclipse.jdt.core_xx.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_xx.jar
```

Usually people add other libraries in folder called lib but still you will have to set it in eclipse. In order to do that right click on your project then `build path -> configure build path -> libraries` and select add JAR.